# merge.xts not merging all data using R

Tags: r, merge, character, numeric, xts

I am trying to reclass the following xts series since columns 1-8 are character and are suppose to be numeric, columns 9-10 are character as they are suppose to be.....

```
# data
x <- structure(c(NA, NA, "41.95", "30.55", "29.05", "23.71", NA, "23.80", 
NA, NA, "18.67", NA, "16.90", "17.10", "14.90", "13.64", "12.70", 
"11.65", "10.75", " 9.75", " 9.05", " 7.95", " 6.70", " 6.02", 
" 5.05", NA, NA, " 0.00", " 0.00", " 0.28", "-0.29", NA, " 0.00", 
NA, NA, "-1.28", NA, "-1.10", " 0.00", "-0.30", "-1.51", "-1.50", 
"-2.66", "-1.50", "-1.45", "-1.15", "-0.45", "-0.75", "-1.38", 
"-0.45", "48.20", "43.20", "38.20", "33.20", "28.25", "23.30", 
"22.25", "21.25", "20.30", "19.35", "18.35", "17.40", "16.35", 
"15.50", "14.50", "13.55", "12.55", "11.55", "10.60", " 9.65", 
" 8.65", " 7.70", " 6.80", " 5.90", " 5.00", "48.80", "43.80", 
"38.80", "33.80", "28.65", "23.65", "22.80", "21.65", "20.65", 
"19.65", "18.65", "17.70", "16.70", "15.65", "14.70", "13.70", 
"12.65", "11.75", "10.75", " 9.80", " 8.80", " 7.85", " 6.95", 
" 6.00", " 5.10", "     0", "     0", "    21", "    27", "     0", 
"   356", "     0", "    82", "     0", "     0", "   323", "     0", 
"   444", "   242", "   223", "  1304", "   362", "   263", "   126", 
"   690", "  1445", "   624", "   476", "   995", "   730", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "   71", "  131", NA, NA, NA, NA, "  435", NA, "   42", 
NA, "  171", "  423", "   83", "   39", "   20", "    6", "  124", 
"   42", "  177", "  425", "  344", " 65.00", " 70.00", " 75.00", 
" 80.00", " 85.00", " 90.00", " 91.00", " 92.00", " 93.00", " 94.00", 
" 95.00", " 96.00", " 97.00", " 98.00", " 99.00", "100.00", "101.00", 
"102.00", "103.00", "104.00", "105.00", "106.00", "107.00", "108.00", 
"109.00", NA, NA, "  0.00", "  0.00", "  0.97", " -1.21", NA, 
"  0.00", NA, NA, " -6.42", NA, " -6.11", "  0.00", " -1.97", 
" -9.97", "-10.56", "-18.59", "-12.24", "-12.95", "-11.27", " -5.36", 
"-10.07", "-18.65", " -8.18", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", 
"Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", 
"Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", 
"Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", 
"Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", 
"Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015", 
"Sep 25, 2015", "Sep 25, 2015"), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(1442534400, 
1442534400, 1442534400, 1442534400, 1442534400, 1442534400, 1442534400, 
1442534400, 1442534400, 1442534400, 1442534400, 1442534400, 1442534400, 
1442534400, 1442534400, 1442534400, 1442534400, 1442534400, 1442534400, 
1442534400, 1442534400, 1442534400, 1442534400, 1442534400, 1442534400
), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(25L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("p", "c", "b", "a", "oi", "vol", "strike", "cp", 
    "callput", "expiry")))
```

What I have done is turned columns 1-8 into numeric by using the following:

`xx <- reclass(apply(x[,1:8], 2, as.numeric), x)`

but when I try to combine it with the last two character columns in `x` called `expiry` and `callput` it turns the character columns into `NA`

`xy <- merge.xts(xx, x[,9:10])`

how can i work around this?

Comment: I think you only have one class in `xts` object. All the columns in `x` are characters, but all columns in `xx` are numeric. And when you try to merge numeric and characters, characters are coerced to numeric, which gives `NA`. See for example the output of `as.numeric("Hello world")`.

Comment: xts (and zoo) objects are a matrix with an index attribute, and you can't mix types in a matrix. So the work-around will depend on what you're trying to do with these data.

Comment: I think I understand now, basically I need the "callput" and "expiry" columns so I can later just call the data via R by those attributes... @JoshuaUlrich the reason why I want `xts` rather than `data.frame` is because I will be `rowbinding` by date as data is added ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xts` is a `matrix` beneath the surface, so it must be all numeric, or all character. With financial applications it normally has to be numeric, so the question becomes what to do with the character columns.

If a character data column can only be one of a few possible values then you actually have a factor. Your call/put column fits this:

```
as.numeric( factor( c("C","C","P"), levels=c("C","P" ) ) )  #1 1 2
```

Obviously, you need to know *in advance* all your factor levels.

If a character column is actually a datestamp, such as your option expiry column, then there are two ways to convert it to a number. One is to use `as.numeric` directly:

```
as.numeric(as.Date("Sep 25, 2015", "%b %d, %Y"))  #16699
```

The other is as an 8-digit YYYYMMDD number:

```
as.numeric(format(as.Date("Sep 25, 2015", "%b %d, %Y"), "%Y%m%d"))  #20150921
```

I prefer the latter, as it is more readable. (But the former if you want to do date arithmetic directly on it.)

Timestamps, and time of day can be handled in the same way.

If you have a character string that does not fit the above cases, the choices are less palatable:

- Use a `data.frame`. (Datestamps in the `rownames`; you can still `rbind` new rows in; `subset` out the columns of interest into an `xts` object when that is what you need)
- Use parallel `xts` objects (nasty code smell).
- An attribute on your xts object. (You can have an attribute on an `xts` object that is an `xts` object. I've used this when the character strings are only for a subset of the datestamps in the main xts object.)
- Wait for the xts class that allows mixed types to be written. :-)