# Merging xts object with character inputs without getting NAs

Tags: r, merge, xts

I am currently working with futures dataset across asset classes - which involves xts objects with numeric and character inputs. I am applying merge() to align the dataset to consistent dates, however, merge() on a xts object with character inputs, as is the case with the below example, gives NAs. Is there a work around?

Below is the dput output of a sample xts object (underlying future contracts):

```
uContracts <- structure(c("SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", 
"SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", 
"SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", 
"SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", 
"SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", 
"SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", 
"SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", 
"SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", 
"SPH00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", 
"SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", 
"SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", 
"SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", 
"SPM00-USA"), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(946598400, 
946857600, 946944000, 947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 
947548800, 947635200, 947721600, 947808000, 948153600, 948240000, 
948326400, 948412800, 948672000, 948758400, 948844800, 948931200, 
949017600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(20L, 3L
), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("SP00-USA", "SP.1-USA", "SP.2-USA"
)))
```

Dput out of sample dates:

```
tW <- structure(c(10956, 10959, 10960, 10961, 10962, 10963, 10966, 
10967, 10968, 10969, 10970, 10973, 10974, 10975, 10976, 10977, 
10980, 10981, 10982, 10983), class = "Date")
```

I would like to format uContracts as per dates in tW, wherein any dates in tW that are not in uContracts, fill underlying contract name from the last available date. I am currently doing that as below:

```
adjContracts <- merge(uContracts, tW, fill = na.locf)
```

The above command works for numeric data (such as prices), but falters for character data. My current output is:

```
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), .Dim = c(21L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("SP00.USA", "SP.1.USA", "SP.2.USA")), index = structure(c(946598400, 
946857600, 946944000, 947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 
947548800, 947635200, 947721600, 947808000, 948067200, 948153600, 
948240000, 948326400, 948412800, 948672000, 948758400, 948844800, 
948931200, 949017600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC")
```

From what I gather, xts is converting the underlying dataset to numeric (from character). I believe, Darren Cook (PS - I hope you are okay with the shoutout) in [merge.xts not merging all data using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685623/merge-xts-not-merging-all-data-using-r) touched upon this issue, but I am not sure how to apply it here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
S

update: below is the expected output (note the difference in the index of the xts object):

```
structure(c("SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", 
"SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", 
"SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", 
"SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", 
"SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", 
"SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", 
"SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", 
"SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", "SPH00-USA", 
"SPH00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", 
"SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", 
"SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", 
"SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", "SPM00-USA", 
"SPM00-USA"), .Dim = c(20L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("SP00-USA", 
"SP.1-USA", "SP.2-USA")), index = structure(c(946598400, 946857600, 
946944000, 947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 947548800, 
947635200, 947721600, 947808000, 948067200, 948153600, 948240000, 
948326400, 948412800, 948672000, 948758400, 948844800, 948931200
), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC")
```

Comment: Can you show what will be your expected output ?

Comment: I have now included that in my question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with the code in the question:

- `tW` was not converted to xts and if that is not done it assumes that the object represents *data* whereas in fact it represents the index
- from the expected output it seems you want only the dates in `tW` to be in the output so the `all=` argument needs to be specified appropriately.

To do this note that zero width xts objects are supported so convert `tW` to an xts object as shown below and then merge `uContracts` with it. From the expected output shown in the question it appears that only the dates in `tW` should be in the result.  In that case, use the `all=` argument shown below. (If instead all dates from both objects were wanted in the output then omit the `all=` argument since the default is `all = TRUE` which retains the dates of both objects.)

```
merge(uContracts, xts(, tW), all = c(FALSE, TRUE), fill = na.locf)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly - kept the column names intact, although I do get a warning for using a zero width xts. Thanks for your help! P.S. - I am new to R and finding my way through how dates and indexing are handled.

Comment: I don't get any warnings.  Make sure you are using the most recent version of xts and then start a fresh R session and copy and paste `tW` and `uContracts` from the question into it.  Then run the code `library(xts); merge(...)` .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a way to solve this without converting the data but it is easier to do manipulation if you convert it into a dataframe. Using functions from `tidyverse` we can do the following

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xts)

as.data.frame(uContracts) %>%
   rownames_to_column('Date') %>%
   mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
   right_join(tibble(Date = tW)) %>%
   fill(everything()) %>%
   column_to_rownames('Date') %>%
   as.xts()

#             SP00-USA    SP.1-USA    SP.2-USA   
#1999-12-31 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-03 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-04 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-05 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-06 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-07 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-10 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-11 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-12 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-13 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-14 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-17 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-18 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-19 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-20 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-21 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-24 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-25 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-26 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
#2000-01-27 "SPH00-USA" "SPH00-USA" "SPM00-USA"
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into the problem. Unfortunately, did not work on the greater dataset.

Comment: @Shriv No problem. If the other answer worked for you, you should consider accepting it by clicking on check mark next to vote button.